# Changing Address list to dropdown select on checkout

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have this code on `Magento_NegotiableQuote/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js`

```
define([

    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    './address-renderer/address',
    'mage/translate',
    'select2',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
], function (
    $,
    ko,
     _, 
     utils, 
     layout, 
     ListView, 
     addressList, 
     AddressModel,
     $t,
     quote,
     checkoutData,
     createShippingAddress,
     selectedShippingAddress,
     customer,
     ) {
    'use strict';

    var defaultRendererTemplate = {
        parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
        name: '${ $.$data.name }',
        component: 'Magento_NegotiableQuote/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default'
    },
    popUp = null,

    newShippingAddressOption = {
        getAddressInline: function () {
            return $t('New Address');
        },
        customerAddressId: null
    },

    shippingAddressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
        return address.getType() == 'customer-address';
    });

    shippingAddressOptions.push(newShippingAddressOption);

    return ListView.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_NegotiableQuote/shipping-address/list'
        },

        shippingAddressOptions: shippingAddressOptions,
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initChildren: function () {
            if (!checkoutConfig.isAddressInAddressBook && checkoutConfig.quoteShippingAddress) {
                addressList.push(new AddressModel(checkoutConfig.quoteShippingAddress));
                this.visible = true;
            }
            _.each(addressList(), this.createRendererComponent, this);
            return this;
        },
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._super()
            .observe({
                selectedShippingAddress: null,
                isShippingAddressFormVisible: !customer.isLoggedIn() || shippingAddressOptions.length == 1
            });
            return this;
        },


        /**
         * @param {Object} address
         * @return {*}
         */
        shippingAddressOptionsText: function (address) {
            return address.getAddressInline();
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} address
         */
        onShippingAddressChange: function (address) {
            this.isShippingAddressFormVisible(address == newShippingAddressOption); //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
        },
        /**
         * Create new component that will render given address in the address list.
         *
         * @param {Object} address
         * @param {*} index
         */
        createRendererComponent: function (address, index) {
            var rendererTemplate, templateData, rendererComponent;

            if (index in this.rendererComponents) {
                this.rendererComponents[index].address(address);
            } else {
                // rendererTemplates are provided via layout
                rendererTemplate = address.getType() !== undefined &&
                this.rendererTemplates[address.getType()] !== undefined ?
                    utils.extend({}, defaultRendererTemplate, this.rendererTemplates[address.getType()])
                    : defaultRendererTemplate;
                templateData = {
                    parentName: this.name,
                    name: index
                };
                rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
                utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                    address: ko.observable(address)
                });
                rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
                utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                    address: ko.observable(address)
                });
                layout([rendererComponent]);
                this.rendererComponents[index] = rendererComponent;
            }
        },


        updateShippingAddress: function () {
            if (this.selectedShippingAddress() && this.selectedShippingAddress() != newAddressOption) {
                selectShippingAddress(this.selectedShippingAddress());
                checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(this.selectedShippingAddress().getKey());
                //  this.isShippingMethodFormVisible(true);
            } else {
                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.data.validate');

                if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                    var addressData = this.source.get('shippingAddress');
                    // if user clicked the checkbox, its value is true or false. Need to convert.
                    addressData.save_in_address_book = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;

                    // New address must be selected as a shipping address
                    var newShippingAddress = createShippingAddress(addressData);
                    selectShippingAddress(newShippingAddress);
                    checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(newShippingAddress.getKey());
                    checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress(addressData);
                    //this.isShippingMethodFormVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            },
        /**
         * Added Select2 to dropdown
         */
        selectTwo:function(){
            $('select').select2({
                theme: "classic"
            });
        },
    });
});
```

`Magento_NegotiableQuote/web/template/shipping-address/list.html`

```
<div class="field addresses">
    <div class="control">
        <div class="shipping-address-items">
            <select class="select2" name="billing_address_id" data-bind="
        options: shippingAddressOptions,
        optionsText: shippingAddressOptionsText,
        value: selectedShippingAddress,
        event: {change: onShippingAddressChange(selectedShippingAddress())};"
        afterRender="selectTwo()"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Two questions here actually, Why am I getting an error saying that
`list.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: customer.isLoggedIn is not a function` when I already declared customer model, And how can i have the `selectedShippingAddress` value added to the options value? Thank you so much for the help, Been struggling with Magento 2 checkout for the past weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwrite **/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js** [OR Magento_NegotiableQuote/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js* if Magento_NegotiableQuote module available] in your custom theme to show drop down shipping address list in checkout page.

I assume you are using a custom theme "**Company_default**".

Please follow the steps describe below.

**step 1)**

Create **list.js** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-address/***

**File** : */app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js*

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'mage/url',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'mage/translate'
], function (_, ko, utils, Component, layout, addressList,  selectShippingAddressAction, checkoutData, url, confirmation, $t) {
    'use strict';

    var defaultRendererTemplate = {
        parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
        name: '${ $.$data.name }',
        component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default'
    };

    /* custom RendererTemplate  for Dropdown*/
    var mydefaultRendererTemplate = {
        parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
        name: '${ $.$data.name }',
        component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/mydefault'
    };

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list',
            visible: addressList().length > 0,
            rendererTemplates: [],
            myAddressList: [],            
            myComponentRendererIndex:50
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super()
                .initChildren();

            addressList.subscribe(function (changes) {
                    var self = this;

                    changes.forEach(function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'added') {                            
                           //self.createNewRendererComponent(change.value, change.index);
                           self.createNewRendererComponent(change.value, 0);
                           self.createRendererMyNewComponent(change.value, change.index);
                        }
                    });
                },
                this,
                'arrayChange'
            );

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initConfig: function () {
            this._super();
            // the list of child components that are responsible for address rendering
            this.rendererComponents = [];

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initChildren: function () {
           // _.each(addressList(), this.createRendererComponent, this);
            _.each(addressList(), this.createAddressListData, this);
            this.createRendererMyComponent();

            return this;
        },
         /**
         * Create arreess List Array
         *
         * @param {Object} address
         * @param {*} index
         */
        createAddressListData: function(address, index){
            //address.inlineAddress = address.getAddressInline();
            this.myAddressList.push( address );
        }, 
        /**
         * Push new shipping address
         */ 
        createRendererMyNewComponent: function(address, index) {
             if (index in this.myAddressList) {         
                 //this.rendererComponents[50].allAddress[index] = address;
             } else {
               this.rendererComponents[this.myComponentRendererIndex].allAddress.push(address);
             } 

        },
        /**
         * Render My Custom Component 
         */
        createRendererMyComponent: function() {
              var rendererTemplate, templateData, rendererComponent;

              rendererTemplate = utils.extend({}, mydefaultRendererTemplate);

              templateData = {
                    parentName: this.name,
                    name: 'shipping-addressall-dropdown'
                };

              rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);               
              this.selectedItem = ko.observable(); 

              this.selectedItem.subscribe(function(latest){
                  selectShippingAddressAction(latest);
                  checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(latest,latest.getKey());
                  this.createNewRendererComponent(latest,0);
                  },this);

              utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                    allAddress: ko.observableArray( this.myAddressList),
                    selectedItem: this.selectedItem,



                });  

             layout([rendererComponent]);                
             this.rendererComponents[this.myComponentRendererIndex] = rendererComponent;


        },
        /**
         * Create new component that will render given address in the address list
         *
         * @param {Object} address
         * @param {*} index
         */
        createRendererComponent: function (address, index) {
            var rendererTemplate, templateData, rendererComponent;

            if (index in this.rendererComponents) {
                this.rendererComponents[index].address(address);
            } else {
                // rendererTemplates are provided via layout
                rendererTemplate = address.getType() != undefined && this.rendererTemplates[address.getType()] != undefined ? //eslint-disable-line
                    utils.extend({}, defaultRendererTemplate, this.rendererTemplates[address.getType()]) :
                    defaultRendererTemplate;
                templateData = {
                    parentName: this.name,
                    name: index
                };
                rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
                utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                    address: ko.observable(address)
                });
                layout([rendererComponent]);
                this.rendererComponents[index] = rendererComponent;
            }
        },
        createNewRendererComponent: function (address, index) {
            var rendererTemplate, templateData, rendererComponent;
            if (index in this.rendererComponents) {
                this.rendererComponents[index].address(address);
            } else {
                // rendererTemplates are provided via layout
                rendererTemplate = address.getType() != undefined && this.rendererTemplates[address.getType()] != undefined ? //eslint-disable-line
                    utils.extend({}, defaultRendererTemplate, this.rendererTemplates[address.getType()]) :
                    defaultRendererTemplate;
                templateData = {
                    parentName: this.name,
                    name: index
                };
                rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
                utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                    address: ko.observable(address)
                });
                layout([rendererComponent]);
                this.rendererComponents[index] = rendererComponent;
            }
        },

    });
});
```

**step 2)**

Create **mydefault.js** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/***

**File :**  */app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/mydefault.js*

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, ko, Component, selectShippingAddressAction, quote, formPopUpState, checkoutData, customerData, $t) {
    'use strict';

    var countryData = customerData.get('directory-data');

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/address-renderer/mydefault'
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super();
            this.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
                var isSelected = false,
                    shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

                if (shippingAddress) {
                  // isSelected = shippingAddress.getKey() == this.address().getKey(); //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                }

                return isSelected;
            }, this);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} countryId
         * @return {String}
         */
        getCountryName: function (countryId) {
            return countryData()[countryId] != undefined ? countryData()[countryId].name : ''; //eslint-disable-line
        },
         addressOptionsText: function (address) {
              if(address.customerAddressId){
                   return address.getAddressInline();
              } else {
                  //var newAddressInline =  address.firstname +' ' + address.lastname +', '+ address.street[0]+', ' + address.city+', ' + address.region
                  //return '[ '+ $t('New Address')+']' + newAddressInline ;
                  return $t('New Address');
              }

        },
        /*selectedAddress: function(param){
            console.log("address param");
              console.log(param);
        },*/
        /** Set selected customer shipping address  */
        onAddressChange: function (address) {   
            selectShippingAddressAction(this.allAddress());
            checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(this.allAddress().getKey());
        },      

        /**
         * Edit address.
         */
        editAddress: function () {
            formPopUpState.isVisible(true);
            this.showPopup();

        },
        /**
         * Show popup.
         */
        showPopup: function () {
            $('[data-open-modal="opc-new-shipping-address"]').trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

**step 3)**

Create **list.html** under ***YUOR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address***

File: */app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/list.html*

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko if: (visible)-->
<div class="field addresses">
    <div class="control">
        <div class="shipping-address-items">

            <!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->          
            <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**step 4)**

create **default.html** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/***

**File**: */app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html*

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="shipping-address-item" css="'selected-item' : isSelected() , 'not-selected-item':!isSelected()">    
    <text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
    <text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
    <text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
    <text args="address().city "/>, <span html="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
    <text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
    <a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

    <each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
        <each args="data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute'">
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'object'">
                <if args="element[attribute].label">
                    <text args="element[attribute].label"/>
                </if>
                <ifnot args="element[attribute].label">
                    <if args="element[attribute].value">
                        <text args="element[attribute].value"/>
                    </if>
                </ifnot>
            </if>
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'string'">
                <text args="element[attribute]"/>
            </if><br/>
        </each>
    </each>

    <button type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            click="editAddress">
        <span translate="'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!--<button type="button" click="selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span translate="'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>-->
</div>
```

**step 5)**

Create **mydefault.html** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/***

**File**: *app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/mydefault.html*

```
<div class="field addresses">
    <div class="control">
       <select  class="select" name="shipping_address_id" data-bind="
        options: allAddress,
        optionsText: addressOptionsText,
        value: selectedItem">
        </select>                
    </div>     
</div>
```

**step 6)**

Remove static content files and cache files.

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
```

**Note :**

Please do above steps for **Magento_NegotiableQuote** module also if "**Magento_NegotiableQuote**" is available in your Magento installation.

## Demo :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However following the steps above,

I  got this error `2019-12-10 09:29:44] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_NegotiableQuote/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/mydefault" component.`

Comment: This does not work on my end. ` options: allAddress,optionsText: addressOptionsText,` where can i get the values for this? Can you post the whole steps and the files maybe? thanks

Comment: The requirements actually resemble what is on your demo. What will happen if a user doesn't have an address yet? Do I need to create mydefault.js then?

Comment: what should mydefault.js look? it wasn't mentioned in your instructions. Thanks

Comment: `app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/mydefault.html` should this be placed on `app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/mydefault.html`?

Comment: doing step 1 and 2 to both Magento_Checkout and Magento_NegotiableQuote  doesnt seem to change the view of the list

Comment: Also @Pritam can you paste the content of your mydefault js here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102036/discussion-between-pritam-info-24-and-elland).

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Got it to work

Comment: Good to know that. I was glad to help you :)

Comment: Maybe you could help me here also :) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298805/adding-customer-address-after-i-click-save-address-on-checkout-page

Comment: How can the dropdown auto select the address that was new added using the `New Address` button?

Comment: @PritamInfo24, I tried your solutions but unable to achieve, what your demo shows. can you please help me to get dropdown works.

Comment: Sorry, i have created same as this but how can i add the text Company...?

Comment: excellent, it works thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I've followed this steps, and in checkout page I can able to see the layout as shown in Demo

The only issue I found that values are not being rendered in my drop-down. By inspect element I can fine the options and optiontext in select element

But I can't able to select/change the dropdown. It is showing blank.

Comment: Can you give some screenshots please.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the above answer of Pritam and put the files under custom theme's Magento_NegotiableQuote module and the shipping address listing correctly but the current selected shipping address is not listing in default.html

Can you please help

Comment: @pritam biswas: can you please help...?